# Ble Indication message is visible even for not paired devices?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

The issue is that I developing application (esp32 based device with NimBle Stack) that send indication message to paired phones ... but I've noticed that indicate messages also available for not paired devices !!

In my case I consider it as security violation

Is there a way to send indicate messages only for paired devices or it will be send to all device that connected over Gatt protocol ?

And if yes then will it be encrypted that nobody could eavesdrop the message ?

Comment: Could you add information on your peripheral? This is highly dependent on your software stack.

Comment: I use esp32 based device with NimBle Stack